# com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderException: Failed to process D:....\app\build\intermediates\transforms\desugar\debug\13.jar

Tags: java, android, dns, ip, dnsjava

I am working with an app in Android Studio. I need to use Java version 8 so I can use one library(dnsjava: https://github.com/dnsjava/dnsjava ).

When I try to use java version 8 writing this in my build.gradle (:app) file:

```
compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8

    }
```

I get this error:
*com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderException: Failed to process D:....\app\build\intermediates\transforms\desugar\debug\13.jar*

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I faced exactly the same issue and I was able to resolve it by following the fix provided [here](https://github.com/ankidroid/Anki-Android/pull/8361).

In a nutshell, you should add the following to your build file:

```
compileOptions {
    coreLibraryDesugaringEnabled true
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}

dependencies {
    coreLibraryDesugaring 'com.android.tools:desugar_jdk_libs:1.1.5'
    ...
}
```

I hope this works for you too :)